# In JavaScript console.log gives me every value from a for loop. However var.text only displays the last value. Why is this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, api

So I am using the Music Graph API to access and display artists similar to the current one (in this case "The Who.") However, when I use a for loop to go through the results, .text(artistNames) only prints the last name in the array (in this case it only prints Pink Floyd even though the array contains more artists.) However, console.log prints every name in the array. How to I get .text to print every name in the array?

Here's my code:

**JavaScript**

```
for (i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {

    var artistNames = response.data[i].name;

    $('#relatedArtists').text(artistNames);

    console.log(artistNames);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="relatedArtists">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **[`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)**, **[`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** will clear the previous data

```
for (i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {    
    var artistNames = response.data[i].name;    
    $('#relatedArtists').append(artistNames);    
    console.log(artistNames);    
}
```

or you can append with previous data with help of **[`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** with callback

```
for (i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {    
    var artistNames = response.data[i].name;    
    $('#relatedArtists').text(function(i,text){ return text + artistNames; });    
    console.log(artistNames);    
}
```

Comment: @PaulFrank If an answer worked for you, it's customary to mark it as accepted by clicking the gray checkmark to the left of it. Thanks!

Comment: Oh sorry bout that, still new to all this. Anyway, thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Because in each iteration you are overriding the previous value of the `div`.

Instead you can create an array with all the names then set that as the text of the `div` by joining the values like

```js
var response = {
  data: [{
    name: 'n1'
  }, {
    name: 'n2'
  }, {
    name: 'n3'
  }]
}

$('#relatedArtists').text(response.data.map(function(item) {
  return item.name
}).join());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="relatedArtists">

</div>
```